# How can I get to know if a running is finished in python syder environment?

Tags: python, process, ubuntu-14.04, spyder

I run the following script in Spyder python environment under Ubuntu 14.04:

```
import os
import dbf

x1 = '/home/beata/Documents/Bias_coorection/Power_pr/CNRM_pr_power1965'
x2 = '/home/beata/Documents/Bias_coorection/Power_pr/CNRM_pr_power1966'
x3 = '/home/beata/Documents/Bias_coorection/Power_pr/CNRM_pr_power1967'

x = [x1, x2, x3]
def conv(x):
    file_name = os.path.basename(x)
    dbf_file_name = file_name + ".dbf"
    return dbf_file_name
def dbf_from_csv(x):
    dbf.from_csv(x, conv(x))

from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(2)
p.map(dbf_from_csv, x)
p.close()
p.join()
```

When I run this scrip I do not get back prompt in the console after the run is finished. When I type `top` in terminal it seems python is stacked. Could someone suggest me a solution how I can get to know if the conversations are ready? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the IPython console you get something which looks loke this:

﻿﻿In [2]:

in the console while if you use a Python console you will get

">>>"

after the script has been run. Otherwise you can of course just add a line like

```
print "FINISHED"
```

as the last line of your code

Comment: Thank you for your help!